# Format of date from a certain JSON and convert in R?

Tags: json, r, date, jsonlite

What format is the date below and how can I convert it?

```
theData <- fromJSON(theUrl)
theData["sampleDate"]
$sampleDate
[1] 1.439165e+12
```

Looking at the data in a browser, sampleDate has the value 1439164800000.
Using jsonlite (*and kind of new to alot of this stuff*)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It is very likely that your data are milliseconds expressed in Unix time, that is, milliseconds (that's why I divide them by 1000) since `1970-01-01`.
Try this:

```
as.POSIXct(1.439165e+12/1000, origin = "1970-01-01", tz = "UTC")
[1] "2015-08-10 00:03:20 UTC"
```

Note that you have to use your right time-zone argument, here I've just used one to show that argument.

Comment: Yep! Is there any way to generalize it? Like:
`as.POSIXct(theData["sampleDate"]/1000, origin = "1970-01-01", tz = "UTC")`

Comment: Yes that code should work. as.POSIXct can operate on a vector.

Comment: As said by RohitDas your code should work because of vectorisations, that is that every element of data you pass to the function will divided by 1000 @Selman

Comment: @Selman unless we are dealing with lists. If the case you should provide a sample of your data with dput

Comment: Yes, it is a list for some reason. so I get an errror:
`as.POSIXct(theData["sampleDate"]/1000, origin = "1970-01-01", tz = "UTC")
Error in theData["sampleDate"]/1000 : 
  non-numeric argument to binary operator`

Comment: Aha, just had to use unlist(). 
It says you are not supposed to write thanks, so I will just say it out loud.

Comment: @Selman does it work? it could be better if you provide a piece, with `dput` of your data, to we can help you better by seeing what kind of data you are dealing with.

Comment: It works if I `x <-unlist(theData["sampleDate"]) ` and use x, so I'll settle for that.
(But didnt succeed in modifying the `theData["sampleData"]` to work with `as.POSIXct`)

Comment: @Selman most likely because that's a list. that's the reason why I asked you to provide a `dput` of your data and update the question with more detail. Users like me want to help but who asks a question has to provide the more detail possible in order to help users to help them.

Comment: great idea to divide the epoch values by 1000, I had a hard time figuring this out. Thanks .